# sshd.log File Size Issue on OpenSSH SFTP Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2008-r2

I installed OpenSSH for Windows (Win Server 2008 R2) as a SFTP solution and it is working great for that. See: [Installing OpenSSH on Windows](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server)

However, the sshd service is producing an unruly log file, sshd.log that has grown to be 75GB over two days and maxed out my C: drive.  After deleting 75GB worth of log file content, it will immediately start taking up file space in the sshd.log.

Any recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Here is my sshd_config file:

```
# $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.84 2011/05/23 03:30:07 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# The default requires explicit activation of protocol 1
#Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
 #MaxSessions 10

#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing, 
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will 
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
#UsePAM no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-ed25519*,ssh-rsa*,ssh-dss*,ecdsa-sha2*
```

Answer (score 0):

The OpenSSH server on Windows isn't really in a 'finished' state yet.

I am not certain, but I strongly suspect that you are going to need to roll your own log rotation task.  OpenSSH depends on the system to do this.  But none of that exists on Windows.

You might also want to decrease your log level verbosity.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. How can I decrease the log level verbosity?  Please advise.

Comment: @12AX7 unfortunately I don't entirely know.  Like I said, that version of openssh really isn't production, so I haven't messed around with it beyond some basic testing.  I suspect you, or someone else, may need to dig into the source or something, since right now the docs aren't really complete.

Answer (score 0):

Adding something like "LogLevel VERBOSE" in the configuration file should change the log level or "LogLevel info". Also you can try adding this under [Service] part.

Simple batch script for deleting files and schedule to do it every day will help you for now. But you should also see what make this OpenSSH service to create so much logs.

Command to put in the batch file to delete the log files should be something like this:
"del "

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations @IvanAk. Well the sshd_config has: 

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

How do I change Log level? I have tried removing the hashtag in from of LogLevel and changing INFO to ERROR but it has no effect.